# How to call block function in other custom module's model file?

Tags: magento2

I am working on Magento 2. I want to use other module's block function to get some data. How can I call that block function in my module's model file ?

Answer (score 0):

From object Manager injected in your model you can do like this :

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Model;

class YourModel extends \SomeClass
{
    protected $_objectManager;
    public function __construct(
    ...............
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    ..............
    ){
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
     }

     public function someMethod()
     {
          $instanceBlock = $this->_objectManager->get('YourVendor\YourModule\Block\YourBlock');
          $instanceBlock->getMethodFromBlock();
     }

 }
```

If it doesn't work then just create an instance of the class in your model like this :

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Model;

class YourModel extends \SomeClass
{
    public $_instanceBlock;
    public function __construct(
    ...............
    \YourVendor\YourModule\Block\YourBlock $yourBlock,
    ..............
    ){
        $this->_instanceBlock = $yourBlock;
     }

     public function someMethod()
     {
          $this->_instanceBlock->getMethodFromBlock();
     }

 }
```